# New subview to NSView only becomes visible seconds later

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, appkit, addsubview

I'm having some trouble in my current project. I am trying to replace a view by calling `removeFromSuperview()` on the old view and then adding the new view using `addSubview()`.
The new view that's coming in is simply a layer-hosting NSView with the contents of the layer set to some image.

This works fine most of time, but when the image happens to be large (42MP loaded from a .arw file in my case), it takes several seconds from execution of the following replacement code to the views actually being visibly replaced.

```
oldView.removeFromSuperview()
view.addSubview(newView)
```

Any ideas as to what might be causing this are highly appreciated.

Comment: Besides loading and decoding and displaying a 42 MP raw image?  Do you expect that to be instantaneous?

Comment: Well, I am creating the layer and setting the image as its contents before the replacement code is executed. I figured that that's when loading and decoding happen and all the replacement code has left to do that depends on the image's size is rendering the bitmap into the screen. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what happens internally to Apple's code, but in general good programming practice would be to do the work "lazily" – not until necessary.  Perhaps a good way to see whether that is the case is to look at whether there is any delay at all when you initially set up the view, image, etc.  If it is doing the work up front, there ought to be a noticeable lag at that point.  Anyway, simply rendering down a 42 MP image probably takes some time; if you want it to display instantly you should pre-shrink it to the size you plan to display it at.